# Does the Microsoft Installer Project extension for VS2017 work correctly with Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

We've updated to Visual Studio 2017 and switched to [Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) (VSTS) as our source control. I've migrated a few old projects and am using the [Microsoft Installer Project extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) to provide compatibility for the original setup projects.

However, there seems to be a potential issue with source control when working with the setup projects. Attempting to make any change results in the error:

> `The command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file 'Setup[Productname].vdproj' is under source code control and is not checked out.`

Modifying files of other projects within the solution work correctly and trigger checkout from the repository.

I have not been able to determine a way to properly check out the setup project and work with it under the new source control. I'm unsure if it's a bug with the extension or if it simply lacks support for VSTS.

Has anyone successfully been able to work with setup projects `(.vdproj)` in conjunction with VSTS? If not, is there a workaround?

**Edit:**

Image of context menu:

[image: Context menu for setup project]

Comment: What're options in the context menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following workaround, since it seems to be a bug in the installer extension:

- Choose 'Open file in File explorer' in your context menu
- Open the project file in your favorite texteditor
- Make a dummy change (adding a space character in an empty spot is enough)
- Visual studio will prompt to reload the project and has explicity checked out the project file.

see also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e39046b7-202a-4bdf-abe4-507ebd078d44/source-control-complaint-when-building-web-setup-projects?forum=vssourcecontrol)

Answer (score 0):

I submit a feedback here: [The command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file 'Setup[Productname].vdproj' is under source code control and is not checked out](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55573/the-command-you-are-attempting-cannot-be-completed.html)

The workaround is that you can check out the project manually. (Right click the installer project > Check out for edit)

Comment: "Check out for edit" is not an option in the context menu. Where do you find this?

Comment: What're options in context menu? This is the screenshot of mine: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhSmHC3_B3LXTogOV

Comment: That is the context menu. However, yours differs from mine. Are you sure you are using Team Services?

Comment: @JYelton Yes I am using Team Services and VS 2017 Enterprise? What's yours' like?

Comment: Also Team Services but VS 2017 Professional. Perhaps that is the difference in menu. Sorry I cannot post a picture at this time.

Comment: @JYelton Try to go to Source Control Explorer > Select vdproj file and right click > Check out for edit. You can descript what're options in context menu if you cannot post a picture.

Comment: I attempted to add an image but imgur appears to be completely broken at the moment. The only source control options in the context menu are **View History**, **Compare with Unmodified**, and **Blame (Annotate)**.

Comment: @JYelton What's the result if you select vdproj file in Source Control Explorer and right click?

Comment: The message shown in Source Control Explorer is "Team Foundation Server is not your current Source Control plug-in." No files are shown. We have "Git" selected as our source control as we are using Team Services (not Team Foundation Services). *(As an aside, I really dislike how Microsoft has decided to name a completely different service almost identically. TS vs TFS.)*

Comment: Based on John Briggs' comment on your MSDN post, I've removed the setup project(s) from source control entirely. I needed to move on with this project and made the decision to omit the setup project from source control. It's a legacy project, and frankly not worth the time trying to figure out yet another of Microsoft's bugs.

Comment: @JYelton I can't reproduce this issue with git (VSTS git team project), just TFVC, I can modify vdproj directly.